# when sending multiple redis write commands in pipeline, do I need to read the return values?

Tags: redis

for example:

```
344         r.Send("HINCRBY", key, set_timestamp, value)
345         r.Send("EXPIRE", key, 84600)
346         r.Flush()
347         //r.Receive()
348         //r.Receive()
```

do I need lines 347 and 348 to be uncommented? I don't care about the return values. Is there an advantage to not reading them?

Comment: Which Redis client are you using? (perhaps also add your language's tag)

Comment: makes no difference which client, this is a server question. I left off golang tag because golang people would yell at me saying something like "THIS HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH GO!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipelined responses are queued in memory until read. See http://redis.io/topics/pipelining

> While the client sends commands using pipelining, the server will be forced to queue the replies, using memory. So if you need to send a lot of commands with pipelining, it is better to send them as batches having a reasonable number, for instance 10k commands, read the replies, and then send another 10k commands again, and so forth. The speed will be nearly the same, but the additional memory used will be at max the amount needed to queue the replies for this 10k commands.

You should read the replies for all requests at the end of the pipeline.

If you're using the Go [`github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis`](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis) package, this can be with by using `Do` as the final call in the pipeline; and calling `Do` with an empty command argument will only flush the output buffer and return all replies. Not only do you want to receive the responses to clear the queue on the server, but getting unexpected responses or errors on a later call to `Do` could lead to hard to find bugs.

Also, since redis 3.2, you have the option of turning off the reply from the server with [`CLIENT REPLY ON|OFF|SKIP`](http://redis.io/commands/client-reply).

Comment: If you don't, the next call to `Do` with a non-empty command will read and discard all of the queued-up replies, although if any of them return an error the last error returned will be returned by `Do`.